# How to print array functions in one single array?

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort, mergesort

I am trying to implement the merge sort, quick sort, binary search, and interpolation search functions.

I have already figured out the two search functions and my code for the merge sort and quick sort methods is mostly complete. I think I am having an issue with my print statements, because I only want the final array to be printed.

When I run the code, I get the error that it has gone out of bounds because each time the method is called, it also reprints the function. I just want the final sorted arrays from both of these methods to be printed.

I just need to figure out how to print out the sorted arrays from these two methods as one array (per method) that shows the sorted list. I tried to convert the method calls to return the values and input them into an array, but this is something that I am not sure can be done.

```
public static void merge_sort(int A[], int l, int r){

 if(l < r){
    int m = (l + r)/2;
    merge_sort(A, l, m);
    merge_sort(A, m + 1, r);
    merge(A, l, m, r);
  }
  System.out.println("Merge sorted array:" + Arrays.toString(A));
  }

  public static void merge(int A[], int l, int m, int r){


  int n1 = m - l + 1;
  int n2 = r - m;

  int L[] = new int [n1];
  int R[] = new int [n2];

  for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
     L[i] = A[l + i];
  }
  for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++){
     R[j] = A[m + 1 + j];
  }

 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int k = 1;

  while(i < n1 && j < n2){
     if(L[i] <= R[j]){
        A[k] = L[i];
        i++;
     }
     else{
        A[k] = R[j];
        j++;
     }
     k++;
  }

  while(i < n1){
     A[k] = L[i];
     i++; 
     k++;
   }

   while(j < n2){
     A[k] = R[j];
     j++;
     k++;
   }
}

  public static void quick_sort(int A[], int l, int r){

 if(l < r){
   int i = partition(A, l, r);
   quick_sort(A, l, i - 1);
   quick_sort(A, i + 1, r);
 }
 System.out.println("Quick sort of Array: " + Arrays.toString(A));

   }
public static int partition(int A[], int l, int r){

int pivot = A[r];
int i = (l - 1);
for(int j = l; j < r; j++){
  if(A[j] <= pivot){
     i++;
     int temp = A[i];
     A[i] = A[j];
     A[j] = temp;
   }
 }

 int temp = A[i + 1];
 A[i + 1] = A[r];
 A[r] = temp;

 return i + 1;

   } 
    // this is the methods 
    // below is the portion of my main that calls the two sort functions
 int left = 0;
    int right = 14;
    int size = 15;
    //int[] quick = new int[15];
    //int[] merge = new int[15];
    quick_sort(intArray, left, right);
    merge_sort(intArray, left, right);
```

I expect an output that looks like an Array sorted elements for both the merge sort and the quick sort methods.

Comment: Okay so I added the print statements underneath the each method calls. This worked and fixed the quick sort. However, I hit another issue in the merge sort. This is the following error:                                                                                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
 at HW3.merge(HW3.java:60)
 at HW3.merge_sort(HW3.java:17)
 at HW3.main(HW3.java:160)

Comment: The following are the lines where the errors are taking place:                         
      while(j < n2){
         A[k] = R[j];
         j++;
         k++;
       }//line 60
 merge(A, l, m, r);// line 17
 merge_sort(intArray, left, right); // line 160

Comment: That a different issue, and if you need help with it, *after* you **debug** the code on your own, ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print inside the sort methods.

Let the caller print the result of the merge. It's about [Separation of Concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), i.e. a method should be concerned about only one thing.

In this case, a sort method should only do sort, not printing too. Printing the result is outside the scope of what a sort method should do.

Comment: Okay so how do I print these? I cannot put a print statement around the method call because they are both void methods. So, do I put them after each method call?